# Query not returning correct value

Tags: mysql, character

i have a table containing varchar fields with values containing three dots, for example 'tpye your message here...' when querying this record i get the string minus the three dots. What could be the issue here? My table has latin_swedish_ci as collation btw.

Comment: are you sure the problem is in mysql - it could be an issue with html rendering of the output. see **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536182/how-to-handle-horizontal-ellipsis-three-dots-character-in-xml-output-through-p)**. maybe just run the query in mysql cli ( or alternative ) to check where the output issue lies

Comment: Are you sure it's not just showing you that view because the program you're viewing it in is truncating it. So it's actually longer than that? What is the length of the varchar columns ? Is that length the same as the text you see?

Comment: if you can show your query would be helpful